# What is the meaning of the notation $cf(add(\mathcal I))$?

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to prover the following claim:

Assume that $\mathcal I$ is an ideal over some infinite set $X$. Then, $cf(add(\mathcal I))=add(\mathcal I)$.

Doe anyone know what is the meaning of the notation $cf(add(\mathcal I))$?

For a set $A$, what is $cf(A)$?

Thank you!

Comment: If I recall correctly, $\operatorname{add}(\mathcal I)$ is a cardinal, not just any set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *additivity* of an ideal $\def\I{\mathcal I}$, is the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that there are $\kappa$ elements $\left<A_i\mid i < \kappa\right>$, $A_i \in \I$ of $I$ with $\bigcup_{i<\kappa} A_i \not\in \I$.

The cofinality of an cardinal $\kappa$ is the smallest cardinal of a cofinal set in $\kappa$, that is the smallest $\lambda$, such set there are $\left<\alpha_i \in \kappa \mid i < \lambda\right>$ with $\sup_{i<\lambda} \alpha_i = \kappa$.

A cardinal is called regular, if ${\rm cf}(\kappa) = \kappa$, so you have to prove that the additivity of an ideal is always a regular cardinal.